# Complete this reasoning? Number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, intuition

I have this really weird confusion with $gcds$ and and basic theory dividing numbers and at the moment, I am stuck at this.

> If $gcd(a,b) = 1$, it means the biggest number that divides them evenly is only $1$. So if $a | mb$, then the smallest $m$ must be $a$ itself because anything smaller than $a$ would imply that….

I can't think what might be the problem. I've tested it out a few a numbers that were relatively prime, but I don't know how to complete the generalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If gcd$(a,b)=1$ then there exists some integers $x,y$ so that 
$$ax+by=1$$

Since you know that $a|bm$ and you need to get $a|m$, you have to somehow get somewhere in the above equality both $bm$ and $m$.

It should be obvious how to do that.

Comment: My number theory is really weak, so this isn't entirely obvious for me...

Comment: @sidht This is not about number theory, just stare at the equation and try to figure out: how can you get both a $m$ and a $bm$ somewhere there? I don't want to write the complete solution, and the hint already sais too much ;)

Comment: Well we have $\lambda bm x + by = 1$.

Comment: @sidht What $\lambda$? Let me ask again, how can you get $m$ both $bm$ in the equation $$ax+by=1$$ And don't look for a complicated answer.

Comment: I got $\lambda$ from the fact that $a|bm$, I guess you want me to say $amx + bmy = m$?

Comment: @sidht Exactly. And you are almost done. You know that $a$ divides both terms on the LHS, what does this mean?

Comment: Well since the LHS will be "integer*x + integer*y", then the RHS will also be an integer, where it is in the form of $m/a$, meaning $a|m$? And if we want $m/a$ to be the smallest (positive) integer ever possible, we want $m/a = 1$, because $1$ is the smallest positive integer. But that precisely would that mean that it is $m = a$? Any small flaws in this argument?

Comment: The first part is right, is better to write it in terms of divisor.multiple though. As for the second part, nothing so far guarantees that $\frac{amx}{a}+\frac{bmy}{a}$ is the smallest possible thing, so there is no way of getting that $\frac{m}{a}=1$.

Comment: Anyhow, the rest of the argument has nothing to do with this argument. So far we proved that if $a|mb$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$, then $a$ must divide $m$.... This shows that $m$ is a multiple of $a$, and is easy to see that any multiple of $a$ has this property.... The smallest $m$ is therefore the smallest multiple of $a$, which is ....

Answer (score 0):

> $a$ and $b$ share a prime factor

If $a|bm$ then $bm$ has all of the prime factors that $a$ has (as least as many times). Suppose that $$a = \prod_{i=1}^n p_n$$where the $p_n$ are prime, but not necessarily distinct. Then $a$ is the lowest number such that $$a = c\prod_{i=1}^n p_n \implies m \ne c\prod_{i=1}^n p_n$$So $b$ must have at least one of the prime factors $p_n$. And if it does, then $\gcd(a,b) \ge p_k$ for some $k$.

Comment: $a$ is the lowest number? You mean $m$ is the smallest number?

Comment: No. $a$ is the only number that is the product of its prime factors. All other numbers that share those prime factors must have additional ones and therefore be greater than $a$.